# Reference full website title with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

When citing a website in Latex, not the full name is displayed. I already tried to change to @MISC, but with no result.

My bibtex reference:

```
@ONLINE{SiteMesh,
   title        = {SiteMesh Home},
   url          = {http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Home}, 
   year         = {WWW}
}
```

When I use the **\citep** command, only a part of the website title is visible.

> (Sit, WWW)

I also wonder is this is the correct way to cite websites for use in a thesis.
Thanks

**edit:** I'm using a template provided by my highschool which makes use of following bibliography-options:

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliografie}
```

With the natbib package:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

The preamble of the .bib file looks like this:

```
@preamble{ "\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} "
        # "\newcommand{\printfirst}[2]{#1} "
        # "\newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1} "
        # "\newcommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1} " }
```

Also, the attempt to use `@misc` in combination with the `\cite{SiteMesh}` command did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Please give a minimal working example

Comment: @Christian Without the proper link to [the page explaining what is a Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), new users usually have no idea what should they do. See also [\[1\]](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks).

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? (The argument of the command `\bibliographystyle`.) `@online` is not an entry type recognized by the most common bibliography styles; that's why I'm asking which bibliography style you're using.

Comment: I'm using apalike

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instead:

```
@misc{SiteMesh,
    title = "SiteMesh Home",
    howpublished = "\url{http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Home}"
    year = WWW,
}
```

And just use `\cite{SiteMesh}` to cite it in text.